# Action Mailer with Devise | Forgot my Password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I'm trying to get the "Forget my Password" option work, but I think I lost it on what to set up.

As I googled I read that Devise has its own Action Mailer so I don't have to generate controllers and model's for it.

So I edited my **config/enviroments/production.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'example.com' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.example.com",
    :port                 => 25,
    :user_name            => 'test@example.com',
    :password             => '123456',
    :authentication       => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

and in my **config/initializers/devise.rb**

```
 config.mailer_sender = "test@example.com"
```

Of curse this didn't' work.

```
 SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
```

I have a strong belief that I messed things up or forgot a bunch load of settings :)

Could anybody guide me on how to Set up the "Forget my Password" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `smtp.example.com` is not valid,

```
 Socket.getaddrinfo("smtp.example.com", "smtp")
 #SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

Comment: Use `rails generate devise:views` to generate devise view and customize the way you like.

Comment: Thank you Very much :) oh, i actually set :enable_starttls_auto => false} . Is this Ok or should i use your code. or is it the same ?